# What is the meaning of the "Launch configuration Main (1) references non-existing project Server." error?

Tags: java

Every time I try to run chocolate(My New Game), I get a error saying

```
Launch configuration Main (1) references non-existing project Server.
```

I remember I deleted my old project Server, is it because of that?

IDE is Eclipse if needed

Comment: You should add a tag for whichever IDE this is happening in.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean?

It means that you have a Launch config whose name is "Main (1)", and that config refers to a project called "Server" that the IDE cannot find.

> I remember I deleted my old project Server, is it because of that?

Well ... if you deleted it, that would explain why your IDE can't find it.

You probably just need to go to the panel where all of the Launch configs are listed and delete the one that your IDE is complaining about.

Comment: Thank you, I would like a quicker method, if I save my project files, create a new workspace, and move my projects there, will that fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry?  What?  Deleting a launch config takes a couple of seconds.